# Linking an action to the button in the view

Tags: views, 8, theming

I'm looking for some tips how to achieve following functionality in Drupal 8.

I have a simple view where I list filds, nothing special. One of the fields is a custom text which is rendered as a button html element. Now, I want to assign a special action to this button, it is a automatic creation of new node.

Any help will be appresated.

Comment: What kind of action would you like to assign to this button?

Comment: Automatically node creation of some type where I could fill up the field values with  fields generated by the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. You'll probably want to create a Component (they don't have Events that trigger them, as opposed to full Rules) and connect them to your Views custom field.

[Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) is a better option though. It's also well integrated with Rules so you can use that instead of a Custom text Field. With VBO you get checkboxes for each Views row and a button for each action you want to perform on a Views row, so you can select more than one row at the same time.